# The equation $x^2=a$ in a finite group $G$ of odd order.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The problem is showing that $x^2=a$ has a solution for each $a\in G$ if $G$ is a finite group of odd order. Heres what I got so far (my lecturer told me to do it this way):

Since $G$ is of odd order, we can express $1_G$ as: $a^{2n-1}=1_G$.

If we multiply both sides by $a$ we get $a(a^{2n-1})=a^{2n}=a$.

Now this is where I am stuck, how do I proceed from here? Any hints are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$(a^n)^2=a{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$$

Comment: And by this you mean I would be able to express an arbitrary $x$ as $a^n$? And in that way get $x^2=a$

Comment: @Max We only need _one_ solution $x$, and that is all.

Comment: ohhhh gotcha! Thanks, I think I get it now.